# R Language program for inverse gaussian distribution

Tags: r

The cumulative density function of Inverse Gaussian Distribution can be written as; F(t; µ,λ)= Φ [√((λ )/t  )  (t/µ-1)]+ 〖exp〗^(2 λ⁄µ)  Φ[- √(λ/t)  (t/µ+1)], Where Φ show the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution. plz tell me how can i write this function in R

Answer (score 0):

The normal distribution is included in R.  See `?qnorm` for details of how to calculate quantiles of the normal distribution.  It will also show you other helpful functions.

Answer (score 0):

The statmod package, available from CRAN, includes the function `pinvgauss()` for the cumulative density function of the inverse Gaussian distribution, as well as other basic probability functions for that distribution. There is an accompanying article:

Giner, G, and Smyth, GK (2016). [statmod: probability calculations for the inverse Gaussian distribution](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016/RJ-2016-024/index.html). *R Journal* 8(1), 339-351.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the `pnorm` of the standard normal distribution.

[image]

```
pinvgauss <- function(x, mu, lambda) {
  a = sqrt(lambda/x) * (x/mu-1)
  b = exp(2*lambda/mu)
  c = -sqrt(lambda/x) * (x/mu+1)
  result = pnorm(a)+b*pnorm(c)
  return(result)
}
```